# how to get dynamic Text from a Tag separated by span

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<Title id ="10" name="Title">
Name
<span>:</span>
Shanthi --// dynamic value
</Title>

String s = driver.findElement(By.id('10')).getText();
```

expected : Name Shanthi

Actual : Name

How to get the full text ? I tried getAttribute("innerHtml") also but no use...

TIA

Comment: Welcome to SO. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61898733/12567365) for notes on one way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='10']"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

String firstname= (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].textContent", element);
```

or

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

Object firstname= js.executeScript("var value = document.evaluate(\"//table[@id='10']/text()\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return value.stringValue;");
String Firstname=firstname.toString();
```

or Suggested by Andrew

```
String name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='10']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
String[] items = html.split("<span .*?</span>");
```

Comment: Just to note: This `//*[@id='10']/text()]` is not a valid xpath selector - there is an extra `]` at the end. Also, even if you correct that, this selector is trying to return text - whereas the Selenium `findElement` method requires an element to be returned.

Comment: I get this Error....
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: when i copied the Xpath it shows /text()[2] .... not sure how to retrieve the 2nd text value